# Binding image StorageFile to XamlCropControl

Tags: c#, image, binding, uwp

I am working with XamlCropControl library [here](https://xamlcropcontrol.codeplex.com/). I can't binding image from StorageFile to crop-control.
As for XamlCropControl, they do like that:

```
 <xamlcrop:CropControl x:Name="Crop" ImageSource="ms-appx:///Assets/wrench.jpg" DesiredAspectRatio="1.0" />
```

But in my case, I need to bind an image that was picked from gallery then pass it to crop-control. I do like bellow, however it did not work at all.

```
  public async void ImageReceiver(StorageFile image)
    {
        BitmapImage bitmapImage = new BitmapImage();
        FileRandomAccessStream stream = (FileRandomAccessStream)await image.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.Read);
        bitmapImage.SetSource(stream);
        ImgParam = bitmapImage;
    }

    private BitmapImage imgParam;
    public WriteableBitmap ImgParam
    {
        get { return imgParam; }
        set
        {
            imgParam = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("ImgParam");
        }
    }
```

And in xaml file:

```
   <xamlcrop:CropControl x:Name="CropControl"
                          ImageSource="{Binding ImgParam, Mode=TwoWay}"
                          DesiredAspectRatio="1.0"
                          Background="Black"
                          Width="100"
                          Height="100"/>
```

Comment: Is `ImgParam` a public property with change notification? And the question is certainly about Windows Store/UWP, not WPF.

Comment: @Clemens : Yes, it is public already, and this app is UWP :D Do you have any clue ?

Comment: Ok, it is public. But is it a property (and not a field), and does it notify about value changes, i.e. does the class that declares the property implement the INotifyPropertyChanged interface?

Comment: Yes, It is. I just added source code in question

Comment: If you don't get around fixing this problem, maybe take a look at an alternative here http://blogs.u2u.be/diederik/post/2015/08/14/An-ImageCropper-control-for-the-Universal-Windows-Platform.aspx

Comment: You probably didn't set the DataContext of the Page to an instance of the class that declares the ImgParam property. So the Binding has no source object.

Comment: I did set the DataContext, and other property work well. The reason I used XamlCropControl is because it provides square crop frame, but not rectangle template as others. So that I can apply crop source to it. I just started with UWP so that edit template is not really easy, I appreciate edit logic source.